# Shopify API call with pagination giving allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29125517 bytes)

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, curl, shopify

I am trying to get all products of the shop by using pagination and also avoiding API Call limit. Guidance to avoid Shopify API Call limit is given on below link: 
[Shopify API Call limit](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-call-limit)
There is **Ruby code** at the bottom of this page. I have used its algorithm to write same code in **PHP**. Below is my code:

```
public function all()
{
    $super_array = array();
    //$shop_domain = 'anystore.myshopify.com';
    $shop_domain = 'another.myshopify.com';
    $shop_data = $this->shop_model->find_shop_by_domain($shop_domain);

    $api_arguments = ['access_token' => $shop_data['shop_access_token'], 'shop_domain' => $shop_domain];

            $products_count = $this->getProductsCount($api_arguments);
            var_dump($products_count);


            $nb_pages = ceil($products_count / 250.0);



            $cycle = 0.5;
            $start_time = time();

            for($page = 1; $page <= $nb_pages ; $page++)
            {
                if($page != 1)
                {

                    $stop_time = time();
                    echo 'Last batch processing started at ' . strftime('%I:%M%p' , $start_time); echo '<br>';
                    echo 'The time is now ' . strftime('%I:%M%p' , $stop_time); echo '<br>';
                    $processing_duration = $stop_time - $start_time;
                    echo 'The processing lasted ' . intval($processing_duration); echo '<br>';
                    $wait_time = ceil($cycle - $processing_duration);
                    echo 'We have to wait ' .  $wait_time .  ' seconds then we will resume.'; echo '<br>';
                    if($wait_time > 0)
                    {
                        sleep($wait_time);
                    }
                    $start_time = time();


                }


                echo 'Doing page ' . $page . '/' . $nb_pages . '...'; echo '<br>';

                $api_arguments['page'] = $page;
                $products = $this->getProducts($api_arguments);
                var_dump(count($products));



            }




            if($products_count === 0)
            {
                echo "You don't have any products in your store duh!";
            }

            $api_data = array(
                'API_KEY' => $this->config->item('shopify_api_key'),
                'API_SECRET' => $this->config->item('shopify_secret'),
                'SHOP_DOMAIN' => $shop_domain,
                'ACCESS_TOKEN' => $shop_data['shop_access_token'],
            );

}



protected function getProductsCount($arguments)
{
    $data = array(
        'API_KEY' => $this->config->item('shopify_api_key'),
        'API_SECRET' => $this->config->item('shopify_secret'),
        'SHOP_DOMAIN' => $arguments['shop_domain'],
        'ACCESS_TOKEN' => $arguments['access_token'],
    );

    $this->load->library('shopify' , $data);

    $args = array(
        'URL' => '/admin/products/count.json',
        'METHOD' => 'GET',
        'RETURNARRAY' => TRUE
     );

    try{

        $response = $this->shopify->call($args);
        return $response['count'];

    }catch(Exception $e){

        $response = $e->getMessage();
            log_message('error', ' In Get  Products Count in ShopifyProxy Controller ' . $response);


    }
}

protected function getProducts($arguments)
{

    $data = array(
        'API_KEY' => $this->config->item('shopify_api_key'),
        'API_SECRET' => $this->config->item('shopify_secret'),
        'SHOP_DOMAIN' => $arguments['shop_domain'],
        'ACCESS_TOKEN' => $arguments['access_token'],
    );

    $this->load->library('shopify' , $data);

    $args = array(
        'URL' => '/admin/products.json?limit=250&page=' . $arguments['page'],
        'METHOD' => 'GET',
        'RETURNARRAY' => TRUE
     );

   try{

        $response = $this->shopify->call($args);
        return $response['products'];

    }catch(Exception $e){

        $response = $e->getMessage();
            log_message('error', ' In Get  Products Count in ShopifyProxy Controller ' . $response);


    }

}
```

Now its throwing the following error :
**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29125517 bytes)** in Shopify API wrapper which I am using to make API calls in CodeIgniter.

[Line on which error is being thrown](https://github.com/ZoobiDoobi/shopify_codeigniter_working_example/blob/master/application/libraries/Shopify.php#L243)
Is there something wrong with my implementation of avoiding API Call Limit?
Any thoughts?